# How can we group and name a series for n consecutive numbers in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Say we have  a series 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 number. If we consider 3 running consecutive numbers then the out must be group as group 1 containing [1,2,3] ,2  containing [4,5,6],3 containing [7,8,9] and 4 containing only [10] in this case.Please share

Comment: The formula output must be only the group numbers 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: So in a column beside the number series you want to put the group number?

Comment: Scott, Yes So in a column beside the number series you want to put the group number . The  whole series must not be in one single cell rather in a column like numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are in each single cell of a column, 1 in cell A1, 2 in cell A2 ....10 in A10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your series is in Column A and you want the group number in Column B:

```
=INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/$C$2)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks indeed Scott!!

Comment: @MutumPamel if this worked for you then please consider marking as correct by clicking the check box by the answer.